# How to fix time presentation from 23:7:42 to 23:07:42

Tags: c++, time, printing, styles

Should I make it a `string` ? or there is a simple way to stay with `int` ?

```
class TimeFixer {
private:
    int seconds=0;
    int minutes=0;
    int hours=0;


public:
    TimeFixer() {
        cout << "Enter hours,minutes,seconds: " ;
        cin >> hours;
        cin >> minutes;
        cin >> seconds;
    }
    void fixTime() {
        while (seconds >= 60) {
            seconds -= 60;
            minutes++;
        }
        while (minutes >= 60) {
            minutes -= 60;
            hours++;
        }
        while (hours >= 24) {
            hours -= 24;
        }
    }
    void displayTime() {
        cout << hours << ":" << minutes << ":" << seconds << endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    int value = 0;
    cout << "Enter value: " ;
    cin >> value;
    TimeFixer *fix1;
    fix1 = new TimeFixer[value]();

    for (int i = 0 ; i < value ; i++) {
        fix1[i].fixTime();
        fix1[i].displayTime();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `setw(2)` and `setfill('0')`? More of a code sample may help.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are asking. Where does the string "23:7:42" come from? Maybe you should show us your code.

Comment: im getting the time from user as  INT hours minutes etc.

Comment: Then @Niall's comment is the correct way to go.

Comment: and how do I fix it in my code

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) for [setw](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) and [setfill](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use setfill () and setw() functions for displaying the data as per your requirement as Suggested by Niall also.

ie. you can use the following manner to display the time.

```
void displayTime() {
   cout << setfill ('0') << setw (2)<< hours << ":"  << setw (2)<< minutes << ":" << setw (2)<< seconds << endl ;
}
```

for example view : http://codepad.org/NNL930Im

Comment: I don't think you need to do use `setfill('0')` before every integer output. Just once at the beginning should suffice. See [http://codepad.org/FqHrTOxm](http://codepad.org/FqHrTOxm).